# Hide empty element on Bootstrap tab via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

HTML:

```
<div class="ys-panel ys-tabs">
        <div class="panel-heading with-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-content-id="id1" href="#">
                        <i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test1"></i> Tab 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a data-content-id="id2" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test2"></i> Tab 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a data-content-id="id3" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test3"></i> Tab 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab active" id="id1">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

             <div class="tab active" id="id2">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

             <div class="tab active" id="id3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Its [Bootstrap tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) and working well. I want if any div hasn't `p` element, hide parent `li`

JS:

```
if ($(".tab").length < 0) {
        $('.nav-tabs li a').parent().hide();
    } else {

}
```

But its not working. What's my problem? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: First if all, `.length` of array can **never** be less than `0`. Second, since there always are three `.tab` elements on page, `$(".tab").length` always equals to `3`. Third, you don't check for having `<p>` in `.tab` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like:

```js
// for each tab link
$('.nav-tabs li a').each(function() {
    // does it's related div (by content id) not have a p element?
    if ($('#' + $(this).data('content-id') + ' > p').length == 0) {
        // if not, find the link's parent li element and hide it
        $(this).parent('li').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ys-panel ys-tabs">
 <div class="panel-heading with-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
   <li class="active">
    <a data-content-id="id1" href="#">
     <i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test1"></i> Tab 1
    </a>
   </li>
   <li><a data-content-id="id2" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test2"></i> Tab 2</a></li>
   <li>
    <a data-content-id="id3" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test3"></i> Tab 3</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="tab active" id="id1">
   <p>...</p>
  </div>

   <div class="tab active" id="id2">
   <p>...</p>
  </div>

   <div class="tab active" id="id3">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it was hide all li tabs.

Comment: @karmaso: I fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(".panel-body .tab:not(:has(p))").each(function() {
  alert(this.id)
  $('a[data-content-id="' + this.id + '"]').closest("li").hide();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ys-panel ys-tabs">
  <div class="panel-heading with-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-content-id="id1" href="#">
          <i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test1"></i> Tab 1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-content-id="id2" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test2"></i> Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-content-id="id3" href="#"><i class="ys-icons ys-icons-test3"></i> Tab 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="tab active" id="id1">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab active" id="id2">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab active" id="id3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to view each element on its own.

With the selector you have (`$(".tab")`) you select all elements with the class *tab*. The length of the selected elements would always be three in your example (because you have three tabs).

To iterate over them take a look at the `.each` function (see other answers). You can either check in this function if the element has any content or improve your selector to do that for you (see `not` filter).