# hide tab in bootstrap if no content present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801567/hide-empty-element-on-bootstrap-tab-via-jquery), but I can not get it to work for me. When I use this script, it hides the tab whether there is a "p" tag or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="product-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-content-id="tab1" data-toggle="tab">Description</a><div class="active-border"></div></li>
    <li class="border-none"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-content-id="tab2" data-toggle="tab">Features &amp; Specs</a><div class="active-border"></div></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-content-id="tab3" class="warranty-tab">Warranty</a><div class="active-border"></div></li>
        <li class="reviews-tab"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-content-id="tab4" data-toggle="tab">Expert Reviews</a><div class="active-border"></div></li>

  <div class="clear"></div>



</ul>


<!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
    <div id="product-description" class="rte">

      <div class="">{{ product.description }}</div>
      <div class="">{{ product.metafields.custom_fields.ProductFeatures }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
    <div id="product-description" class="rte">
      {{ product.metafields.custom_fields.ProductMoreInfo }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
    <div id="product-description" class="rte">
      {{ product.metafields.custom_fields.Warrantee }}
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
    <div id="product-description" class="rte">
      {{ product.metafields.custom_fields.ExpertReviews }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the script I borrowed from the other thread and modified for my needs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  <script>
// for each tab link
$('li.reviews-tab a').each(function() {
// does it's related div (by content id) not have a p element?
if ($('#tab4' + $(this).data('content-id') + ' > p').length == 0) {
    // if not, find the link's parent li element and hide it
    $(this).parent('li.reviews-tab').hide();
}
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the comments of your javascript correctly, you will need something like this instead.

```
// for each tab link
$('#product-tabs a').each(function() {

    // does it's related div (by content id) not have a p element?
    if ($('#' + $(this).data('content-id')).has('p').length == 0) {

        // if not, find the link's parent li element and hide it
        $(this).closest('li').hide();
    }
});
```